# Having trouble transferring audio data from iOS to another device which uses PyAudio to play it

Tags: ios, audio-streaming, pyaudio, portaudio

I am using [novocaine](https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine) to get mic audio data and [PyAudio](https://github.com/jleb/pyaudio) on another computer to play the audio.

I am using [WAMP](https://github.com/mogui/MDWamp) to send over the data, so far data sends just fine.

But I am having trouble trying to get the data received from the mic on iOS device to play on the Py device.

Novocaine returns an array of floats when getting audio so I figured I do this in order to transfer the data properly.

```
NSMutableData *outBuffer = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:0];
[outBuffer appendBytes:&newAudio length:sizeof(float)];
```

When playing with the data on python device I get a length of 4 however, when I try to print it out there is always a problem is UTF formatting issue.

[Basic of playing audio with PyAudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#docs)

I am unsure how I should be translating this float audio data.

Edit:

```
Novocaine *audioManager = [Novocaine audioManager];
[audioManager setInputBlock:^(float *newAudio, UInt32 numSamples, UInt32 numChannels) {
    // Now you're getting audio from the microphone every 20 milliseconds or so. How's that for easy?
    // Audio comes in interleaved, so,
    // if numChannels = 2, newAudio[0] is channel 1, newAudio[1] is channel 2, newAudio[2] is channel 1, etc.
}];
[audioManager play];
```

Comment: Can you show what you are trying to do on the Python side?

Comment: @Matthias [This is the gist of it](https://ghostbin.com/paste/ad374). I was able to use this code for python to send over audio data while capturing audio on my laptop using Python as well. Feels like possibly a format issue.

Comment: And where does the "UTF formatting issue" happen?

Comment: @Matthias after some playing around. I am only getting float values. I am unsure if that is exactly what I want for Port Audio. Not sure if there is anything i can do with regards to how Novocaine is giving me the audio data as an array of floats, but PyAudio seems to work whenever the data is something like [this](https://ghostbin.com/paste/rf4rh), bytes.

Comment: So yeah NSData helped with it. Just got to make sure to buffer properly and usually it works well.